# Thymeleaf / SpringBoot : Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type float for property

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template

```
<input type="text"    th:field="*{purchasePrice}" ../>
```

mapped to this property:

```
private float purchasePrice;
```

But I have this error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type float for property purchasePrice; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,132872"
```

I've trie also with

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type float for property purchasePrice; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.132872"
```

I also tried with  `<input type="text"    th:field="${purchasePrice}"   .../>`

but the I got this error

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'purchasePrice' available as request attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your `private float purchasePrice;` is defined in a simple POJO class. Let's say the POJO is named `Price`:

```
public class Price {
    
    private float purchasePrice;

    public float getPurchasePrice() {
        return purchasePrice;
    }

    public void setPurchasePrice(float purchasePrice) {
        this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    }
}
```

To make `*{purchasePrice}` visible in the view you should first add `Price` to a modelAttribute in your Controller class:

```
 @GetMapping("/")
 public String index(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("price", new Price());
     return "index";
 }
```

The HTML form looks simple as:

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/price}" th:object="${price}">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{purchasePrice}" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="value" class="link-button">This
        is a link that sends a POST request</button>
</form>
```

You see that I add a new field called `th:object="${price}"`.

> Command object is the name Spring MVC gives to form-backing beans,
> this is, to objects that model a form’s fields and provide getter and
> setter methods that will be used by the framework for establishing and
> obtaining the values input by the user at the browser side.

The mapping for the post request is looks like the following:

```
@PostMapping("/price")
public String index(@ModelAttribute Price price) {
    return "index";
}
```

So if I send the value `0.132872` its converted to the object `Price` and holds the value `purchasePrice = 0.132872`;

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It should not be

field="*{purchasePrice}"

Rather it should be

th:field="${purchasePrice}"